# displaying multiple divs with jquery when clicking on radio button

Tags: jquery, html

i have an issue. i want to display the different input field when clicking on the different radio button.
when you click on 1, Telephone1 field should appear.
when you click on 2, both Telephone1 and telephone 2 should appear
and lastly when you click on 3,all three input field should appear.
i'm new at jquery don't know how to do it. 
here is my HTML CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JQuery tests</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<h1>JQuery tests</h1>
<form>
<label>Telephone: <em>*</em></label>

<input type="radio" name="Telephone"   value="telephone1"  />1

<input type="radio" name="Telephone"   value="telephone2"  />2

 <input type="radio" name="Telephone"  value="telephone3" />3
                                       <br/><br/>

<div id="Telephone1" style="display:none">
  telephone1: <input type="text" name="reference"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>

<div id="Telephone2" style="display:none">
  telephone2: <input type="text" name="reference"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<div id="Telephone3" style="display:none">
  telephone3: <input type="text" name="reference"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("input[name='Telephone']:radio")
.change(function() {

$("#Telephone1").toggle($(this).val() == "telephone1");
$("#Telephone2,").toggle($(this).val() == "telephone2".val()=="telephone1");
$("#Telephone3").toggle($(this).val() == "telephone3");

 });
</script>

</body>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this, but I usually focus on the selection:

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/zefsszom/

```
$("input[name='Telephone']:radio").change(function () {
    $('.telephone').hide();   // Hide them all
    switch ($(this).val()) {
        case "telephone1":
            $("#Telephone1").show();
            break;
        case "telephone2":
            $("#Telephone1,#Telephone2").show();
            break;
        case "telephone3":
            $('.telephone').show();
            break;

    }
});
```

**Note:** I added a common class to make hiding/showing *all* telephone inputs easier.

More often than not I tend to data-drive this type of scenario:

e.g. put the selectors in the values:

```
</label>
<input type="radio" name="Telephone" value="#Telephone1" />1
<input type="radio" name="Telephone" value="#Telephone1,#Telephone2" />2
<input type="radio" name="Telephone" value="#Telephone1,#Telephone2,#Telephone3" />3
<br/>
```

then the code simplifies to something like:

```
$("input[name='Telephone']:radio").change(function () {
    var selection = $($(this).val());
    $('.telephone').not(selection.show()).hide();
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/zefsszom/1/

Comment: Glad it helps. Go with the second data-driven setup where possible. Please accept as answer when you can. Thanks.